# How to collect Spark JavaPairRDD data as list

Tags: apache-spark, java-pair-rdd

I am working on an Apache Spark 2.2.0 task in java and I currently perform a `mapToPair()` function over my `JavaRDD<String>` and I get a result of `JavaPairRDD<Integer, Table>`. Consider `Table` as any Object type.

What I am trying to do now, is to collect all of the data into a final list that would be returned to the driver program. I don't want to perform any transformation, aggregation or calculation over the data, that's why I thought of using the `collect()` function.

What I have so far is the following:

```
JavaPairRDD<Integer, Table> pairs = gData.mapToPair(...);
JavaRDD<Tuple2<Integer, Table>> t = JavaRDD.fromRDD(pairs.rdd(), null);
List<Tuple2<Integer, Table>> el = t.collect();
```

But for some reason that I can't understand it produces the following error...

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method com.google.common.base.Stopwatch.<init>()V from class org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:312)
```

I might be totally on the wrong direction, but can you suggest a way to collect these Tuple2 data and possible iterate over them?

Thank you.

---

**Update** No matter what my code does, even if I try to run the simple word count example, then the error of `Format.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:312)` still comes up! Any help?

Comment: which version of spark you are using, I am running the same steps as you have mentioned with spark 2.1.0 and scala 2.11 , and it working. I able to collect the JavapairRdd

Comment: try .`collectAsList()`

Comment: Hi, I use spark 2.2.0. I guess I have to convert my `JavaPairRDD` into `Dataset` to use `collectAsList`?